# Global keyboard function in Autohotkey?

Tags: windows, function, keyboard, global, autohotkey

This script "auto-presses" E while holding it down.

```
    $e::
While GetKeyState("e","P")
{
    Random, r, 50, 250
    sleep r
    Send e
}
return
```

Is there a way to globally call this function for any key?

For example: Holding A, will auto-press A and Z will auto-press Z, etc.

Without manually assigning every possible key on the code.

Comment: Hey, are you really sure with the delay before sending the key ? I mean you will not get the keys send in the same order you type it because of the difference in the delays.

Comment: Btw, you also have the option to create an Autohotkey script containing mappings of all the letters by using another script of language of your choice.

Comment: Yes, the random key-pressing is intended to mimic the behavior of a real person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to catch all keys. But you can simplify your code by combining hotkeys this way:

```
$a::
$b::
$c::
; and so on...
$z::
RandomSendCurrentKey()  ; all the above hotkeys will call RandomSendCurrentKey()
return  ; 'return' is needed to prevent further execution

RandomSendCurrentKey() {
    local key
    StringReplace, key, A_ThisHotkey, $,, All  ; removes '$' from key   

    While GetKeyState(key, "P")
    {
        Random, r, 50, 250
        sleep r
        Send %key%
    }   
}
```

But why do you need a `while` loop? It should work without a `while` too since AutoHotKey will keep calling the function as long as you press the key:

```
$a::
$b::
$c::
$z::
RandomSendCurrentKey()
return

RandomSendCurrentKey() {
    local key
    StringReplace, key, A_ThisHotkey, $,, All  ; removes '$' from key   

    Random, r, 50, 250
    sleep r
    Send %key%
}
```