# Array in Autohotkey?

Tags: arrays, list, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

Is it possible to assign this code to several keyboard hotkeys?

```
$1::
StringReplace, ThisKeyLabel, A_ThisLabel, $
While GetKeyState(ThisKeyLabel,"P")
{
    Random, r, 50, 250
    sleep r
    Send % ThisKeyLabel
}
return
```

Where $1 (hotkey <kbd>1</kbd>) would be replaced with a list or array.

For example: $hotkeys(<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global keyboard function in Autohotkey?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654733/global-keyboard-function-in-autohotkey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Example

```
; List of keys to bind
keys := "wasd"

; bind the keys to keypress_handler
Loop, parse, keys
    hotkey, ~%A_Loopfield%, keypress_handler

; our key handler
keypress_handler:
    StringReplace, ThisKeyLabel, A_ThisHotkey, $
    While GetKeyState(ThisKeyLabel,"P")
    {
        Random, r, 50, 250
        sleep r
        Send % ThisKeyLabel
    }
Return
```

Comment: How do you replace the `MsgBox` with the `While Getkeystate` function?

Comment: How do you do this for keys which are numpad keys?  For example, Numpad1 and Numpad2?

Comment: Do a loop line parse instead of a single character by character loop, see the appropriate documentation on loops in the AutoHotkey docs. :)

Comment: `~%A_Loopfield%` is why **~**? its not work and this remove is work

Comment: @KingRider Could be your system is different. Anyhow, it is explained here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

Comment: @JoeDF i see a version v1.1.14, used version diferent is not work `~` ... thanks and i go update version.